# Can ‘them’ be used for ‘their’ in front of a noun?

Tags: pronouns

I’m having a difficulty understanding “could they just have that for them unreachable pleasure” in the following sentence. If *them* means *their*, my questions will be solved. I’ll take it like this: if they could just have a piano for their unreachable pleasure. But I’m not familiar with such case. Am I misunderstanding something important? Or does the ‘them’ mean ‘their’?

> Owning a piano is for some a symbol of status. That’s very sad, because there are many gifted people who would like to give anything, could they just have that for **them** unreachable pleasure, that is now just looking decorative and impressive in somebody’s interior. (*People and Pianos* by Marinus J. van Prattenburg: p9) [bold font is mine]

Just for your information, the writer is a Canadian and lives on the west coast. (though I don’t know whether it’s relevant.)

Comment: If that's an accurate transcript, I suspect the writer may be one of the [24% of Canadians](http://www3.telus.net/linguisticsissues/french.html) for whom English is not their mother tongue. To me, *many gifted people who would* **like to** *give anything* looks more like a "translation" than something a true native speaker would say. Well, to be honest, so does the whole excerpt.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The writer was born in the Netherlands and immigrated into Canada at age thirty-two. I don’t know how old he is but he seems to be an elderly man from the picture. And … yes, I’ve seen “would give anything” in _Harry Potter_ books but never “would like to give” unless my memory fails me. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The phrase "for them unreachable" is an adjectival phrase which describes "pleasure". It is to be parsed as "...could they just have that pleasure (which is unreachable for them)".

Comment: +1 - I think @Billy is correct.  Most of the time a sub-clause like "for them unreachable" would be delimited with commas on either side, but since it's positioned in a sub-clause, adding the extra commas would make it equally awkward.  <opinion>That whole sentence would benefit from a rewrite.</opinion>

Comment: @oosterwal Though I’m not an English speaker, I think your opinion is true.

Answer (score 3):

The actual phrase would be **"have that unreachable pleasure."** Because the pleasure of owning a piano is not unreachable for everyone, however, the author wants to clarify that it's unreachable *for them*.

You would generally see such a phrase offset by commas or parentheses to avoid just such confusion: "...to have that, for them, unreachable pleasure..."

Comment: I didn’t understand one important thing. Your words, ‘Not unreachable for everyone’, was a key to my aha moment. Thanks a million!