# Using "them" in lieu of "their"

Tags: word-choice

In the chorus of the song "Gone Country" by Alan Jackson, there is this sentence:

> She/He's gone country, look at **them** boots

How come `them` is used instead of `their`? I am not a native English speaker so I am interested in knowing about this peculiar (at least to me) word choice.

This [existing thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43759/can-them-be-used-for-their-in-front-of-a-noun) would tend to indicate that `them` can be used for `that`, but `look at that boots` don't really make sense?

Comment: "Them" is probably replacing 'those' not 'their'... Question still stands though.

Comment: *Them* is not probably but most definitely replacing *those*, not *their*. And the question stands as a duplicate of a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

In some English dialects, but not any Standard Englishes as far as I know, *them* is used where standard English uses *those*.

**Edited** for clarity: this is just a lexical oddity of those dialects. It is not part of a paradigm, so it does not mean that *they* can be used in a similar way, or the singular *it*: just the word *them*.

Comment: I see you had already posted while I was typing my answer. I agree but I don't quite understand what you are saying about 'they or it'. Could you explain? Thanks.

Comment: I'm interested in your analysis of "those them" as in "those them boots need a good clean"

Comment: In line with your comment, I've simplified and updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Marv Mills' comment.

'Them' is a dialect alternative to 'those'.

Note that 'them' is plural here because the person has two boots. Another example: "Look at them trees over there."  This means "Look at those trees over there"

Comment: So what does it mean in "Look at those them trees over there?"

Comment: @Araucaria That sentence is not grammatically correct. It has no meaning.

Comment: @Araucaria - I don't understand your question. I didn't type the collocation 'those them' in my answer.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I'm asking because, although I completely agree that *them* is used similarly to *those* in dialects that use it as a determiner like this, the collocation *those them* also occurs in some of those dialects. So that raises the question of whether *them* means exactly the same thing as *those*. Of, course it still could, but it might suggest that it carries some other kind of meaning too.

Comment: I have never read or heard, 'those them' (in this sense). Could you give an example please? Preferably a link to such an example on the internet. Thanks.

Comment: One from the web "kudos to the dude who sold those them Aug 7 puts, they ain't worth nothing now-well .02cents."[here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/534914-world-of-warcraft/43641743)

Comment: "Those them types that f*** with me" --->  Those **are** them types that f*** with me". The verb is omitted.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK "Well actually it is those them there smart aleck's who have read the small print, know the small print and use the small print ..." [here](http://www.everyreq.com/blog/2014/11/stick-em-up)

Comment: @Araucaria - Hmm... You seem to have found some recent slang. I've never encountered it before. I understand what's happening but I think it would need a separate question with a separate answer to explain fully. It's  a different meme from the one asked about in this question.